# Hausdorff Space and functions

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ be continuous where $Y$ is Hausdorff. Prove that if $f(x)=g(x)$ for each $x$ in a subset $A$ of $X$, then $f(x)=g(x)$ for each $x$ in $\overline{A}$.

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
Let $y\in \bar{A}$ be so that $f(y)\ne g(y)$. The space $Y$ being Hausdorff, implies there exist open sets $U_1$ and $U_2$ such that $$f(y)\in U_1,\;g(y)\in U_2\text{ and }U_1\cap U_2=\varnothing.$$

Now $f^{-1}(U_1)$ and $f^{-1}(U_2)$ are open sets in $X$ containing $y\in \bar{A}$, therefore
$$f^{-1}(U_1)\cap A\ne \varnothing\text{ and }f^{-1}(U_2)\cap A\ne \varnothing$$
Now ...

Answer (score 0):

The core idea is that if $X$ is Hausdorff then the diagonal $\Delta \subset X \times X$ is closed (this is a basic fact you should be able to prove).

Observe you can define the function $(f,g)\colon X\rightarrow X \times X$ by $(f,g)(x)=(f(x),g(x))$ which is clearly continuous, thus $\{x \in X : f(x)=g(x) \}=(f,g)^{-1}(\Delta)$ is closed and this gives you the proof of the statement.

Comment: But in my question, $X$ is not necessarily Hausdorff.

Comment: Sorry, I made some confusion. My argument still works perfectly if you replace the target of $f,g$ with $Y$: this space is Hausdorff so $\Delta \subset Y \times Y$ is still closed, hence its preimage via $(f,g)$ is closed.